# How to include render method as attribute to Route using Reach Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reach-router

I want to make protected route using Reach Router. In React Router v4 I could use Route render() method to achive this:

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

and then declare route:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/protected" component={Protected} />
```

I don't know how to access or modify render() method in Reach Router:

```
<Router>
        <Results path="/" />
        <Details path="/details/:id" />
</Router>
```

How can I do this using Reach Router? There has to be a better way then writing conditions in render() method inside a protected component.